# S3 CORS responding with 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to enable CORS on an S3 bucket. Here's my CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

If I try to access any of the files in my bucket, the server responds with a 403 and the following:

```
<Error>
  <script/>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>A0DDB22DAA8FEB96</RequestId>
  <HostId>
    wamh2M0Q2rfW2RAXdnJThqeWxVSxd2P2VVq0izvwipp2JATIipMc9CvAs9Qe+2iC
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

If I remove the CORS configuration, everything works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This might be because you haven't explicitly specified the allowed headers which are usually sent in pre-flight requests when calls are made through CORS.

Ideally, you also need to specify the maximum time the browser can cache these pre-flight requests. Try modifying your CORS configuration to include this information as follows:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error with this configuration.

Comment: Could you also post the access policy document for your bucket? There could be a conflict between the two.

Comment: Are you talking about what's under the **Add Bucket Policy** button? If so, it's empty.

Comment: Could you also possibly post the code you're using to access your bucket? Or are you just hitting the URL?

Comment: I'm hitting the URL directly in Chrome.

Comment: You might need to look at the permissions on the individual file you're accessing. Could you try right clicking on the file in the S3 management console and setting it to "Make public" and then try? In this case, you'll need to set the appropriate access level when you're uploading the file. The default is private.